# FileNotFoundException Error creating Database WP8 Sqlite

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sqlite-net

I am following [[this](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone)](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone) tutorial to create an application with an SQLite database.

When I executed it, I got **System.IO.FileNotFoundException** pointing to the file **SQLite.cs**, the line where the error originated is shown in the screen shot below(in the SQLite.cs file)

[image: error line]

Below is the code snippet for creating a database

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");
if (!FileExists(dbPath).Result)
{
   using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
   {
        db.CreateTable<Person>();
   }
}
```

and the method FileExists

```
        private async Task<bool> FileExists(string fileName)
        {
            var result = false;
            try
            {
                var store = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
                result =true;
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            return result;

        }
```

I am wondering what went wrong. Any help?

Comment: Why do you use File.Exists without passing the path used to create the file?

Comment: @Steve I just corrected that now and the same error still persist

Comment: The ! operator will flip the result so if FileExists returns false then the code will run which is not what you want I think.

Comment: :-) how come I missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the line `if (!FileExists(dbPath).Result)` you're saying that if the file doesn't exist, connect to the database and create a table. So your condition is wrong, because the line

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName)
```

wants an existing file to execute correctly.
Correct then your `if` condition with:

`if (FileExists(dbPath).Result)`